# How is output passed as input in pipes?

Tags: shell, pipe

I am trying to understand how pipes `|` work; in particular, in what way the output from the left command is passed as the input to the right command. Is the output from the left command treated as a file that is passed as an argument to the right command, i.e., is

```
a | b
```

the same as

```
a > a_output
b a_output
```

This would mean that `b` takes a filename as input and reads it. But this would seem to make things like

```
cat wonderfulfile | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
```

impossible, since `tr` does not take a filename as input. Or is the output of the left command treated as standard input for the right command, i.e., if

```
a
```

prints

```
f
g
h
```

to the screen, is

```
a | b
```

the same as

```
b
f
g
h
^D
```

or perhaps

```
b f g h
```

or

```
b 'f g h'
```

This would seem to contradict lines like

```
who | less
```

since less, at least without options, requires a filename. Thank you for your help.

Comment: "A pipe basically just connects the stdout of one process to the stdin of another, effectively piping the data from one process into another." https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Pipes  (not sure why it hedges by saying "basically")

Comment: "A pipeline is a set of processes chained together by their standard streams, so that the output text of each process (stdout) is passed directly as input (stdin) to the next one." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

Comment: `less` and other programs "knows" when input and/or ouput are a  terminal, a file or a pipe and can behave accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s the second option: in

```
a | b
```

anything that `a` outputs to its standard output is provided on `b`’s standard input.

Your perceived contradiction isn’t one: `less` without options reads from its standard input (unless it’s a terminal, in which case it fails), without requiring a file name.

Comment: `$ less
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)
$ less f
f: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try actually piping something into it, *e.g.* `who | less` as in your own example.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to understand what is the equivalent of piping. Is the output of who taken as an argument to less, like `less $(who)`, which doesn't seem to work, or if it is taken as standard input as if you typed less, pressed Enter, and then starting typing things, why does `less` fail when I type it on its own?

Comment: `less` checks whether its standard input is a terminal; if it is, it requires a file name, but if it isn’t, it reads from it. Try `less <<<Hello`.

Comment: Very interesting and important to know! Is there an official source where that is written? I didn't find it in `man less`.

Comment: I can’t find it documented, it’s [visible in the `less` source code](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/7ffbe025fa433fed0d7719899ea75e8fa942727b/edit.c#L904).

Answer (score 1):

> Is the output from the left command treated as a file that is passed as an argument to the right command

No.

The pipe connects the standard output to the standard input. That's really what it does. Just as your `>` redirects the standard output to a file, `|` redirects the standard output stream into the stream that is the standard input of the second command.

In other words, whenever program `b` does something like `read`ing from the input, it reads what `a` has put onto its output. No file in between – the pipe is the integral "connection" between the output and the input. "standard output" and "standard input" are two streams every program has under a UNIX-style operating system (and also, most other operating systems for PC-style hardware).

Comment: What about programs like `less`, which, at least without options specified, require a file as an argument? In `who | less`, doesn't `less` expect a filename?

Comment: It does *not* require an argument. `less` without a file argument just reads from its standard input.

Comment: `less -` makes it read stdin as a file, and also use the terminal input as command keys (Linux Mint 19.3) with unpleasant results. Needed to `Ctrl-Z` and `kill %1` to end it, as `Ctrl-C` and `Ctrl-D` etc are apparently trapped.